# How do I jump to method implementation for C++ code in Android Studio (1.5.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, clion, intellij-15

I've got a lot of native code, and I want to be able to right click a function name -> Go To -> Implementation(s). I can do this with Java code just fine, but when I try it on my C++ code, it always jumps to the function definition in the header file, not to the implementation in the .cpp file. This is extremely frustrating. Is anyone else having this problem? Anyone find a solution?

Comment: Why are you tagging this with CLion and IntelliJ when the question is about Android Studio?